# recursively call own class by @Inject In spring

Tags: java, spring

```
@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class Product extends Factory

{
@Inject
protected Product product;

protected void something(){}

protected void thatThing(){ 

}
```

Below Exception is being thrown

> found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency.
>        Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
>       :292)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>           Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scope is set to prototype, the Spring IoC container creates new bean instance of the object every time a request for that specific bean is made.

And in your code, you have a member product. So every time you need a new product, the framework will create a new member instance of product. And recursively, the member will create it's member again. So it is obviously improper.

I think, maybe it should be like this:

```
@Named
public class ProductBuilder extends Factory {

  @Inject
  protected Product product;

  protected void something(){}

  protected void thatThing(){ 

}
```

Then for your product, define the bean as prototype:

```
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class Product {
  ....
}
```